# Why I receive blank page? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have been learning React for few days and I wrote simple project (single page application). Problem is that my page doesn't show anything - it's a blank page.

**App.js**

```js
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Routes,Route,} from "react-router-dom";
import { Home } from './components/Home';
import { Wallet } from './components/Wallet';


function App() {
  return (
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
          <Route path="/wallet" component={Wallet}/>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Wallet.js**

```js
import React from "react";

export function Wallet() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Wallet Page!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Home.js**

```js
import React from "react";

export function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home Page!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So when I go to http://localhost:3001/ or http://localhost:3001/wallet I receive blank page. Could someone point me where I made a mistake?

Comment: you should put more detail about the project. How did you generate the project

Comment: In Home.js you've named the function `Wallet` but I assume it should be `Home`.

Comment: Blank page === check the browser console for errors

Comment: My mistake when i copy code, ofc there is a Home function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `react-router-dom@6` the `Route` components render the routed content on the `element` prop as a `ReactNode`, i.e. as JSX. There is no longer any `component`, or `render` and `children` function props.

[Routes and Route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route)

> ```
> declare function Route(
>   props: RouteProps
> ): React.ReactElement | null;
>
> interface RouteProps {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   element?: React.ReactNode | null;
>   index?: boolean;
>   path?: string;
> }
> ```

Move the components into the `element` prop and pass them as normal JSX instead of as a reference to a component.

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/wallet" element={<Wallet />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```