# How to setup React Router with Webpack in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-redux, webpack-5

New to webpack, I tried to configured React Router Dom + webpack but Webpack bundle will not load react router component in react js,

Problem: When run build, I see only `<h1>React Router Example</h1>` tag result in the page, it not load  component, Could you please anyone help this issue or share any links

Expected:
When run react application using Webpack, I need to see this component should load in the page `<Route exact path="/" component={<Home/>} />`

Note:  component only not loading If try load single component without Router It will load

index.js

```
 import React from 'react';
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
 import App from './app';

 ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js

```
import { Route, Routes, Link, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
 const App = () => {
    return (
       <Router>
          <h1>React Router Example</h1>
          <Routes>
             <Route exact path="/" component={<Home/>} />
             <Route path="/login" component={<h1>Login</h1>} />
         </Routes>
      </Router>
      );
    };

   export default App;
```

webpack-config.js

```
        module.exports = {
              entry: './src/index.js',
              output: {
                path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
                filename: 'index_bundle.js',
                publicPath: '/',
              },
              module: {
                rules: [
                  {
                    test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/i,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: 'babel-loader',
                  },
                  {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                      'style-loader',
                      { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
                      'postcss-loader',
                    ],
                  },
                ],
              },
              devServer: {
                historyApiFallback: true,
              },
              plugins: [
                new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                  template: './src/index.html',
                }),
              ],
            };
```

Comment: Is the page actually loading but the content is just blank? I suspect it's just because you're using the incorrect `Route` component props. Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71864686/why-i-receive-blank-page-react

Answer (score 0):

You can use Switch

```
{/* A Switch looks through its children Routes and renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}

    <Switch>
      <Route path="/">
        <Home />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
```

For more check the URL - https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: It not working <Switch> is old version tag, When i build normal it works but when build with webpack (bundle), it not working